# Python Dropbox Core API: getting dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] 'invalid_grant'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api

Trying to follow Dropbox Core Python documentation step by step but hung at this point due to unexpected error.

```
elif args.sync:
    print("syncing")
    import dropbox
    flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(dropbox_appKey, dropbox_appSecret)
    authorize_url = flow.start()
    print("1. Go to: ", authorize_url)
    print("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)")
    print("3. Copy the authorization code.")
    code = input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip
    access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)
    client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
    print("linked account: ", client.account_info())
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./eldiario", line 92, in <module>
    access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dropbox/client.py", line 1233, in finish
    return self._finish(code, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dropbox/client.py", line 1101, in _finish
    response = self.rest_client.POST(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dropbox/rest.py", line 316, in POST
    return cls.IMPL.POST(*n, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dropbox/rest.py", line 254, in POST
    post_params=params, headers=headers, raw_response=raw_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dropbox/rest.py", line 227, in request
    raise ErrorResponse(r, r.read())
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] 'invalid_grant'
```

Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Comment: have you got any soution for it?

Comment: Not yet! And I'm not catching up this issue.

Comment: For this problem i started using oauth.io , and getting the desired result. Still if u get some solution for it kindly let me know. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some parentheses after `strip`.

It should be something like this:

```
code = input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()
```